# Spring mvc ZonedDateTime conversion to UTC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, binding, utc

I woudl ike to convert all java8 ZonedDateTimes into UTC time zone on the server side of the application.  I am successfully binding the Java 8 jsr310 date data types into a spring RestController using the @DateTimeFormat.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/test-date", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public TestCollection findPrivilegesByRoleList(
        @RequestParam(value = "local-date", defaultValue = "2015-05-10") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate requestParamDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "local-date-time", defaultValue = "2015-05-16T15:55:56") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime requestParamLocalDateTime,
        @RequestParam(value = "zoned-date-time", defaultValue = "2015-05-18T11:55:56-04:00") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime requestParamZonedDateTime
        )
```

For the ZonedDateTime class, I would like to shift all input ZonedDateTimes to UTC time, so the server side is always working in UTC timezone.   Following best practice #3 - Store it in UTC
http://apiux.com/2013/03/20/5-laws-api-dates-and-times/#comments

For JSON deserialization, I have a custom deserializer for ZonedDateTime that shifts any timezone into UTC.

```
....
//Parse string into a zoned date time with the specified timezone offset - EST, CET, EDT, PST, ect.
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimewithTimeZone = ZonedDateTime.parse(string, formatter);

//Shift the date time  to UTC Time
return zonedDateTimewithTimeZone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

What is the best way to do the conversion in the controller binding?  I understand this may be forcing multiple responsibilities into the same class, however I want to avoid adding the

`ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant`

call for every date in every controller.
Thanks